# ¿Como puede tomar el valor de día en el que se seleccione y en base a eso dar un precio en datepicker?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estoy trabajando con 2 datepicker el primero es la fecha inicial y el segundo la final, lo que necesito hacer es que dependiendo el dia en los que seleccione me ponga diferente precio.
Por ejemplo:
De lunes a jueves $3000.
De viernes a domingo $4000.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases por la sección de [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que mejores tu pregunta, y cuentanos que haz intentado en base a lo que solicitas, podrias ingresar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "DD", // Sólo obtener DD en lugar de " DD, MM, yy"
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("p.dia").html("Día = " + dateText); //  el día de la semana
      //hacemos la comparación día/precio
      if (dateText == "Monday" || dateText == "Tuesday" || dateText == "Wednesday" || dateText == "Thursday") {
        $("p.precio").html("$3000");
      } else if (dateText == "Friday" || dateText == "Saturday" || dateText == "Sunday") {
        $("p.precio").html("$4000");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <label>Seleccione día</label>
  <input id="datepicker" type="text">
  <p class="dia"></p>
  <!--Se muestra el día seleccionado-->
  <p class="precio"></p>
  <!--Se muestra el precio correspondiente al día-->


</body>

</html>
```

Básicamente haces una comparación específica del día de la fecha previamente seleccionada en el datepicker y muestras el precio que le corresponde.

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Como puedo realizar lo que hiciste pero con 2 datepicker, dependiendo los días seleccionados  será el precio que se le asigne según el día correspondiente ?

Comment: Es decir,¿deberá arrojar el precio final, el cual, será la suma del precio del primer datepicker más el segundo?

Comment: Necesito hacer algo parecido a lo de una reservación en un hotel. Por ejemplo mi fecha inicial es viernes 16 de noviembre del 2018 y mi fecha de salida es el domingo 18 de noviembre del 2018. El día 16 y 17 son los días que voy a comparar y dependiendo el día que sea asignarle un precio. Gracias por tu ayuda .

Answer (score 0):

Se entiende la idea de lo que quieres hacer, pero no queda en claro en que lugar de tu html tienes los datos, aquí realice una función que puede ayudar a guiarte

```js
function myFunction() {
    var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha").value;
    if(!fecha) return false
    var valorg1 = 3000; // Estos valores no estoy seguro si los tienes en un Input o algo asi 
    var valorg2 = 4000;
    var d = new Date(fecha);
    var G1 = [0,1,2,3];//GRUPO1 >> 0 = Lunes, 1= Martes, 2 = Miercoles, 3 = Jueves
    var G2 = [4,5,6] //GRUPO2 >> 4 = Viernes, 5 = Sabado, 6 = Domingo
    if(G1.includes(d.getDay())){valorfinal = valorg1;}else{valorfinal = valorg2;}
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = valorfinal;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">VER VALOr</button>
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Necesito hacer algo parecido a lo de una reservación en un hotel. Por ejemplo mi fecha inicial es viernes 16 de noviembre del 2018 y mi fecha de salida es el domingo 18 de noviembre del 2018. El día 16 y 17 son los días que voy a comparar y dependiendo el día que sea asignarle un precio, los valores los tengo en  input. Gracias por tu ayuda...